# Home Page Banner Slideshow Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to have an image slideshow with change captions on a home page I'm working on. I was using w3schools as the tutorial and I have it working on there, but when I put the code into my text editor nothing happens; nothing is rendering. I'm using Atom and running the code in its html preview screen and have the file open in my browser. I'm using external CSS and JavaScript files and using css-grid for the layout.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="headerpark.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption One</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="headerpark2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="headerpark3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.mySlides {display: none}

.slideshow-container {
   grid-area: banner;
   height: auto;
   max-height: 100vh;
   position: relative;
   justify-self: stretch;
}

.slideshow-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And lastly my JavaScript:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

Comment: You say: "*...when I put the code into my **text editor** nothing happens*".  What kind of text editor is it? Does it have browser emulation?

Comment: I'm assuming your using the browser to check it... when you say "nothing happens", what do you mean? Is all the html and css rendering how it should but the javascript doesn't work?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code at all. It has to be how you're trying to test it. This is an example of your exact code working with the images swapped for placeholders. You'll notice I've added a console.log to make sure it is firing correctly, if you right click on the image and choose Inspect Element (in Chrome) that will show you the logs. http://jsfiddle.net/sbzty5ue/

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm using atom, just pulled it up in notepad++ and same results. There's nothing rendering when I run the code in a browser.

Comment: How are you running the code? What other code is there in the file? Are you getting any console errors when you inspect the code?

Comment: Also keep in mind that you have everything hidden for 5 seconds, so technically nothing will show until the first iteration of the timeout.

Comment: @RickCalder I'm running into the same issue no matter how I test it. Even with codepen there's nothing rendering. Ran it in Chrome, Firefox, Codepen, even uploaded the files to the actual server and still nothing. yoursite.carterswebdesign.com is the site with all the files active.I was trying to do freelance work last year and realized I was way out of my league.

Comment: Codepen link please? @carter92j

Comment: @RickCalder https://codepen.io/carter92j/project/editor/XrLGdp

Comment: @carter92j can you set that to be not readonly please? You're getting a console error it isn't defining "slides"

Comment: @RickCalder all I have is the basic codepen account haven't used it that much, how do I change it from readonly?

Comment: No idea, the error this is returning is confusing. I copied it to a pen I can work on, give me a few :)

Comment: The issue is it's erroring because you're trying to manipulate the dom before those nodes exist. Give me a few here and I'll provide a solution for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Try copying it into an online IDE such as codepen.io and see if it works. It may just be your browser (emulator?).

Comment: Yeah I'm using atom and running the file in Chrome.

Comment: @carter92j Okay! That could explain it. Try codepen.

Answer (score 0):

It was trying to set block on the first slide before the slides collection existed, making sure slides is not undefined before calling that line fixes it.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  console.log(slideIndex);
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

  if( typeof slides[slideIndex-1] !== 'undefined') {
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  }
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

Now if you want to get a little fancier, this is a solution from a friend that creates a class so you can do things like instantiate it with options like time, or create a pause. Both solutions work with your code just by replacing the JS

```
class Slideshow {
  constructor({delay = 5000, selector} = {}) {
    this.delay = delay
    this.index = 0
    this.selector = selector
    this.timeoutRef = undefined
  }

  play() {
    console.log(this.index)
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides')
    slides.forEach(slide => slide.style.display = 'none')
    slides.item(this.index).style.display = 'block'
    this.index = this.index >= slides.length - 1 ? 0 : this.index + 1
    this.timeoutRef = setTimeout(this.play.bind(this), this.delay)
  }
}

const slideshow = new Slideshow({ selector: '.mySlides'})
slideshow.play()
```

Comment: thank you! It's working now! Been stuck for two days. Glad I could give you challenge lol.

Comment: Glad I could help, and honestly loading the JS file at the bottom of the page probably also would have fixed it... I'm tired lol. If you could just check this as the correct answer that would be great :)

Comment: yeah I'm trying to have it start with the load of the document now, and removing an 'invisible' slide after it cycles through. But I checked it as correct, but being a new user it didn't  affect it.